Gauss-Newton method diverge for overdetermined system of equations, would Levenberg–Marquardt work?
Problem set up:
Consider the system of non-linear equation that I have
$F(X) = (F_1(X),F_2(X),.....,F_m(X))^T = 0 $
where $\  X = (x_1,x_2,x_3)\in {\rm I\!R}^3 $ and $ F_i(X) = x_1 + x_2 * a^{x_3} + b \ $    is the non linear equation
The update role for Gauss-Newton I'm using is
$ X_{k+1} = X_{k}-\ J(X_{k})^{\dagger}\ F(X_{k}) = X_{k}-\Delta X_{k} $
with  $ \Delta X_{k} $ is the solution of the linear system $\  J(X_{k}).X = F(X_{k}) $ found using least square solution for overdetermined linear system of equation. $\  J(X_{k})$ and $ \ J(X_{k})^{\dagger}$ are the jacobian matrix and  pseudoinverse of the jacobian respectively.
Behavior/Issue: Using an educated initial guess of $\ (x_1,x_2,x_3)$, the start sum of squared residual is around 400. After the first update, the sum of squares is around 3e+9. At the second iteration it's very large number > 1e+100. Trying manually and playing with the initial guess changed the number slightly but it still diverge in the second step!
What I tried: In an attempt to fix it, I tried to reduce the step size by multiplying $ \Delta X_{k}$ with a fraction $ \ 0 < a << 1$  but this just extended its life to another update before it diverges!
My question: Is this behavior due to something wrong with my implementation or is it because some of the Gauss-Newton method limitation? What can I do in this regard?
My thinking is :
1- I have some doubt about the suitability of Gauss-Newton method to my function $ F_i(X) = x_1 + x_2 * a^{x_3} + b \ $ as I learned that it's approximating the Hessian matrix for function like $F=\sum r_i^2$ and I'm not sure if this can be extended functions like mine
2- If this is a method limitation, what are other method that can overcome this issue. I'm thinking of trying Levenberg–Marquardt to control the step size adaptively but my experiment with the fraction $ \ 0 < a << 1$ makes me also doubt this direction and if I'm missing something!
